# How to retrieve a specific element of a website by scraping with R rvest?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am looking for some help with the following website for a molecule that I am working with:
[chebi_molecule](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=CHEBI:64162)

I would like to extract exactly this text (from the "Roles Classification" table, about in the middle of the webpage):

> Biological Role(s):
>   serotonergic agonist
>   An agent that has an affinity for serotonin receptors and is able to mimic the effects of serotonin by stimulating the physiologic activity at the cell receptors. Serotonin agonists are used as antidepressants, anxiolytics, and in the treatment of migraine disorders.
>
> Application(s):
>   serotonergic agonist
>   An agent that has an affinity for serotonin receptors and is able to mimic the effects of serotonin by stimulating the physiologic activity at the cell receptors. Serotonin agonists are used as antidepressants, anxiolytics, and in the treatment of migraine disorders.

I tried to get the xpath using firefox's firebug v2.0.19 but once I pasted it into rvest html_nodes, I could not retrieve anything.

```
xpath_bio <- ".//*[@id='content']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div"
```

`xpath_appl <- ".//*[@id='content']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div[2]"`

When I try to use:

```
bio <- rvest::read_html(site) %>% html_nodes(xpath = xpath_bio)
```

I get an empty value

Can you help me with this? How can I get exactly those texts? I looked around for other squestions, but I could find so much of a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `html_nodes(".chebiTableContent:nth-child(9)")`.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to scrape that site? Just you can, it does not mean you shold. You can be involved in severe issues with unethical scraping. This is clearly a friendly advice!

Comment: Mine is only academic interest, I do not intend to scrape that website or any other.

Comment: Thank you very nice! MrFlick could you explain how your solution works? Why is the 9th?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `rvest` before, but have you tried using the inspect feature? `ctrl+shift+I` in chrome. I inspected the website for the "biological roles" element and you get this html:

```
<a href="chebiOntology.do;jsessionid=8D8CE11C3CA44298C0BC62921779562B?chebiId=CHEBI:24432" target="_blank">Biological Role</a>
```

So just use regex to find where you have the string `"target="_blank">Biological Role"` and look for the corresponding `"class="roleDefinition""` string.

```
<div class="roleDefinition">An agent that has an affinity for serotonin receptors and is able to mimic the effects of serotonin by stimulating the physiologic activity at the cell receptors. Serotonin agonists are used as antidepressants, anxiolytics, and in the treatment of migraine disorders.</div>
```